To what extent can we regard the result of approximate message passing as "exact + Gaussian noise"?
Suppose now we have a Gaussian sensing matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times M}$ with $M \gg n$, and $A_{ij} \sim_{iid} N(0,\nu)$. We know this matrix $A$.
And now let $x \in \{0,1\}^M$ be a $K$-sparse vector, with $\|x \|_0 = \| x\|_1=K$. And we do not know $x$, but know an observation $y =  Ax + n$, with $n_{i} \sim_{iid} N(0,1)$.
One can use approximate message passing algorithms to recover $x$, leading to an estimate of it called $\hat{x}$. It is often referred that we can regard $\hat{x}$ as $\hat{x} = x + \delta$, with $\delta \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\delta_i \sim_{iid} N(0,1 + \sigma_t^2)$. In practice, one can "estimate" the value of $\sigma_t^2$ by evaluating the variance of the AMP residual, however, I want to know is there any theoretical result can tell us something about this $\sigma_t^2$ value, using $n,M,\nu$ and $K$?
